# 'ssl handshake failure' using requests

Tags: python

I am going through a list of URLs to get some information, but one keeps generating a SSL handshake problem. I found many similar issues on stackoverflow, but none provided me with a working answer.
if the site cannot be reached, I would like to catch the exception to move to another url. At the moment, the code crashes...

I hope someone will be able to help me...

Here is the code:

```
import requests

myurl = 'https://adviseme.mit.edu/'

class Quality_Check:
    def check_broken_link(self,data):
        try:
            url = requests.head(data, verify=False)
            print(url.status_code)
            if url.status_code == 200 or url.status_code == 302 or url.status_code == 301:
                return True
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
            print('false!')
            return False

qc=Quality_Check()
qc.check_broken_link(myurl)
```

Comment: This "https://adviseme.mit.edu/" is the secured one, if you want to access it, you need their certificate. Try accessing that site from a web browser like chrome or firefox.

Comment: Chrome or firefox cannot access it either. What I would like to understand is how to catch the exception from within the python code, so that the code does not crash.